# Matrix left division of stacked arrays using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-einsum

I'm working on a program to solve the Bloch (or more precise the Bloch McConnell) equations in python. So the equation to solve is:

[image: Bloch McConnell equation]

where **A** is a ***NxN*** matrix, **A+** its pseudoinverse and **M0** and **B** are vectors of size N.

The special thing is that I wanna solve the equation for several offsets (and thus several matrices **A**) at the same time. The new dimensions are:

- A: MxNxN
- b: Nx1
- M0: MxNx1

The conventional version of the program (using a loop over the 1st dimension of size M) works fine, but I'm stuck at one point in the 'parallel version'.

At the moment my code looks like this:

```
def bmcsim(A, b, M0, timestep):
    ex = myexpm(A*timestep) # returns stacked array of size MxNxN
    M = np.zeros_like(M0)
    for n in range(ex.shape[0]):
        A_tmp = A[n,:,:]
        A_b = np.linalg.lstsq(A_tmp ,b, rcond=None)[0]
        M[n,:,:] = np.abs(np.real(np.dot(ex[n,:,:], M0[n,:,:] + A_b) - A_b))      
    return M
```

and I would like to get rid of that `for n in range(ex.shape[0])` loop. Unfortunately, `np.linalg.lstsq` doesn't work for stacked arrays, does it? In `myexpm` is used `np.apply_along_axis` for a another problem:

```
def myexpm(A):
    vals,vects = np.linalg.eig(A)
    tmp = np.einsum('ijk,ikl->ijl', vects, np.apply_along_axis(np.diag, -1, np.exp(vals)))
    return np.einsum('ijk,ikl->ijl', tmp, np.linalg.inv(vects))
```

However, that just works for 1D input data. Is there something similar that I can use with `np.linalg.lstsq`? The `np.dot` in `bmcsim` will be replaced with `np.einsum` like in `myexpm` I guess, or are there better ways?

Thanks for your help!

**Update:** 
I just realized that I can replace `np.linalg.lstsq(A,b)` with `np.linalg.solve(A.T.dot(A), A.T.dot(b))` and managed to get rid of the loop this way:

```
def bmcsim2(A, b, M0, timestep):
    ex = myexpm(A*timestep)
    b_stack = np.repeat(b[np.newaxis, :, :], offsets.size, axis=0)
    tmp_left = np.einsum('kji,ikl->ijl', np.transpose(A), A)
    tmp_right = np.einsum('kji,ikl->ijl', np.transpose(A), b_stack)
    A_b_stack = np.linalg.solve(tmp_left , tmp_right )

    return np.abs(np.real(np.einsum('ijk,ikl->ijl',ex, M0+A_b_stack ) - A_b_stack ))
```

This is about 3 times faster, but still a bit complicated. I hope there is a better (shorter/easier) way, that's maybe even faster?!

Comment: Perhaps I should finish off my attempt to make lstsq work on stacked matrices...

Comment: I would definitely appreciate it @Eric

Comment: I make no promises of continued support, but if you look at the source of lstsq, you'll find a call to a lapack gufunc. That inner function _does_ work on stacked matrices - it's just not plumbed through because the bizarre design of the returned `residuals` is incompatible.

Comment: Thanks again! I temporarily changed the `lstsq` function (removed the `_assertRank2`, got rid of resids, ranks, s and checked the dimension at all steps). As u said, the calculation works! However, in my case it is unfortunately about 20% slower than my code using `np.linalg.solve(A.T.dot(A), A.T.dot(b))` :(